# Multiple copy operations in one transaction with SVNKit (like svnmucc)

Tags: svn, svnkit

I would like to be able to perform multiple move (copy and delete) operations within a single SVN transaction (revision), exactly the same way [svnmucc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnmucc.re.html) does it, only using SVNKit 1.7.8.

Could anyone familiar with the SVNKit APIs point me in the right direction?